# C - allocating a single integer

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc

I'm experimenting with pthread library and I've got the following piece of code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < NUM_THREADS; j++)
{
     int *threadNum = malloc(sizeof(int));
     *threadNum = j;
     pthread_create(..., (void *)threadNum);
}
```

Since there is no free, this code has a memory leak. Where should I place free to avoid memory leaks? If I simply write something like:

```
int *threadNum = 0;
*threadNum = j;
```

This leads to a segfault. And I can't place free inside the scope, because I'm using pthread_join in the next few lines.

Comment: > This leads to a segfault.

Of course it does. You're dereferencing a pointer to null (0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call free when you're no longer using your allocated memory.

Presumably, that's after your join, but since your integers are allocated inside the loop, you would need to keep a reference outside the loop.

Rather than allocating your integers individually, consider allocating all of them at once, outside the loop:

```
int *threadNums = malloc(sizeof(int) * NUM_THREADS)

for (int j = 0; j < NUM_THREADS; j++) {
  threadNum[j] = j;
  pthread_create(..., (void *)&threadNum[j]);
} 

//something to ensure the threads are done using the memory

free(threadNums);
```

(Not tested for syntax errors, but hopefully you get the idea)

Pay special attention to the comment. If your threads are not done with the memory before you call free, you have a race condition which causes undefined behavior. One way of ensuring that is to join all of the threads.

Alternatively, if the data is only used be the thread, the thread could be responsible for freeing the memory - in that case, you call free on your pointer when the thread function no longer needs it.

Comment: Incidentally, this'll save quite some memory, since malloc's bookkeeping overhead is amortized among all threads. But OTOH, it will cause some cacheline sharing, hopefully threadNum isn't accessed very frequently, lest its cachelines bounce a lot between CPUs.

Comment: @ninjalj: Correct. Optimal performance in multithreaded code is quite complex. :)

Comment: This code has undefined behavior due to a serious race condition (the data will be `freed` potentially before all the threads are able to read it).

Comment: @R.. `//something else down here` is supposed to have joins for all threads. At least that's how I've read this answer.

Comment: @ninjalj: Your interpretation is correct. @R: As I state in the very first line, you free the data when you're done with it - and you're not done with it until the threads are done accessing it. Joins are one way of doing it; another one is to use a memory barrier at a point where the threads no longer need to refer to that data. While it is certainly common that threads need the data until they're done, it is not guaranteed to be true, and in certain cases, however rare they may be, you may prefer freeing the memory before the threads are actually joined.

Comment: My key point was that someone new to threads reading your code would not realize that you need to synchronize that free, **even if the threads only read the array as the very first line of their start function**, and nonetheless their code would work "most of the time", which is very dangerous. A comment to the effect that some synchronization is needed would make this an acceptable answer.

Comment: @R: It is my interpretation that the OP is aware of that part, but I've made it more explicit anyway.

Comment: @ninjalj to avoid cacheline issues it would be enough to allocate CACHELINE_SIZE * NUM_THREADS and assign each cacheline to a different thread (this also means obviously ensuring that the memory returned by malloc is cacheline aligned).

Answer (score 7):

The thread which uses it (since it is passed as the parameter) should free it when it is done with it.

Comment: Assuming OP wants to continue the silliness of `malloc`'ing a single `int`, this is the best answer. It should be the thread's responsibility to `free`.

Answer (score 3):

*Never* do this! You will lose `threadNum`'s value every time you loop, that's a *huge* memory fault! You should allocate an array with NUM_THREADS elements before the loop and free when you don't need it anymore!

Comment: Agreed, was about to answer this but refreshed before posting.

Comment: Actually, isn't threadNum passing as an argument to the function ? (which can then be `free()`d ?

Comment: The current thread will lose the threadNum.  But each created pthread will have the value, and be able to manage its lifetime.  As long as the threads take ownership and responsibility for the pointers they were passed, there's no memory fault that i can see.

Comment: @Muggen: I don't agree with @wallyk's answer, I think `phtread_create()` won't call `free()`

Comment: I can't say if wallyk changed his answer in his 5-minute window where edits aren't tracked, but his point is that the thread *can* free it. `pthread_create` itself won't, but that doesn't mean the threaded function itself can't.

Answer (score 2):

How about this: create an array of NUM_THREADS size, and with each iteration you can assign j to the jth index in the array. Then you can pass the address of the array index to each pthread_create call, and it would also not require any dynamic allocation.

Comment: You don't need to assign anything to the array. The array can merely be `static const dummy_array[NUM_THREADS];` and then `ptr-dummy_array` yields the index.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply write your code like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < NUM_THREADS; j++)
{
     pthread_create(..., (void *)j);
}
```

Then there is no allocation involved. Cast the thread start function's argument back to `(int)` to use it. Since you're using `pthread_create`, you're targetting a POSIX system, which means you don't have to deal with all the nonsense plain C allows whereby this type of casting might not work.